# How to get h264 bitrate

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, decoding, x264

Tried MediaInfo, tried `ffprobe -show_streams -i "file.mkv"` (or raw file.h264) and it gives me `bit_rate=N/A`. MediaInfo gives nothing at all.

The only way I found out is by creating the .dga file by indexing it via MegUI and the using its Bitrate Calculator tool and setting the same exact size like the source, then it shows the average bitrate, but this way is ridiculous and who knows how accurate.

Answer (score 1):

well, H.264 raw-data does not contain any timing information. You can however extract the frame size and by giving a frame-per-second parameter you can calculate the bitrate.
I wrote a simple bash-script for this that uses awk and ffmpeg (ffprobe).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Mimic the output of
# mplayer -lavdopts vstats FILE -fps 30 -vo null
# Example usage:
# ./vstats.sh file.hevc 30

FFPROBE=$HOME/src/ffmpeg/ffprobe

fps=$2
# default 30 fps
: ${fps:=30}

frames=$3
# Numper of frames to process
: ${frames:=65536}

awk -v FPS="${fps}" -v FRAMES="${frames}" '
BEGIN{
    FS="="
}
/pkt_size/ {
  br=$2/1000.0*8*FPS
  if (br > max_br)
      max_br=br
  acc_br+=br
  acc_bytes+=br
  i+=1
  printf("frame= %6d, f_size= %7d, s_size= %8dkB, br= %8.1fkbits/s, avg_br= %8.1fkbits/s\n",
      i, $2, int(acc_bytes/1024+0.5), br, acc_br/i)

  if (i >= FRAMES)
      exit 
}
END {
    print "----"
    printf("Peak BR: %.1fkbits/s", max_br)
}
' <(${FFPROBE} -show_frames $1 2>/dev/null)
```

Example output:

```
frame=      1, f_size=   50805, s_size=       12kB, br=  12193.2kbits/s, avg_br=  12193.2kbits/s
frame=      2, f_size=    4749, s_size=       13kB, br=   1139.8kbits/s, avg_br=   6666.5kbits/s
frame=      3, f_size=    5781, s_size=       14kB, br=   1387.4kbits/s, avg_br=   4906.8kbits/s
frame=      4, f_size=    6135, s_size=       16kB, br=   1472.4kbits/s, avg_br=   4048.2kbits/s
frame=      5, f_size=    6239, s_size=       17kB, br=   1497.4kbits/s, avg_br=   3538.0kbits/s
frame=      6, f_size=    6487, s_size=       19kB, br=   1556.9kbits/s, avg_br=   3207.8kbits/s
frame=      7, f_size=    6550, s_size=       20kB, br=   1572.0kbits/s, avg_br=   2974.1kbits/s
frame=      8, f_size=    6567, s_size=       22kB, br=   1576.1kbits/s, avg_br=   2799.4kbits/s
frame=      9, f_size=    6390, s_size=       23kB, br=   1533.6kbits/s, avg_br=   2658.7kbits/s
frame=     10, f_size=    6540, s_size=       25kB, br=   1569.6kbits/s, avg_br=   2549.8kbits/s
frame=     11, f_size=    6929, s_size=       27kB, br=   1663.0kbits/s, avg_br=   2469.2kbits/s
frame=     12, f_size=    8037, s_size=       28kB, br=   1928.9kbits/s, avg_br=   2424.2kbits/s
frame=     13, f_size=    7965, s_size=       30kB, br=   1911.6kbits/s, avg_br=   2384.8kbits/s
frame=     14, f_size=    7833, s_size=       32kB, br=   1879.9kbits/s, avg_br=   2348.7kbits/s
frame=     15, f_size=    8281, s_size=       34kB, br=   1987.4kbits/s, avg_br=   2324.6kbits/s
frame=     16, f_size=    8235, s_size=       36kB, br=   1976.4kbits/s, avg_br=   2302.8kbits/s
frame=     17, f_size=    7969, s_size=       38kB, br=   1912.6kbits/s, avg_br=   2279.9kbits/s
frame=     18, f_size=    7953, s_size=       40kB, br=   1908.7kbits/s, avg_br=   2259.3kbits/s
frame=     19, f_size=    8867, s_size=       42kB, br=   2128.1kbits/s, avg_br=   2252.4kbits/s
frame=     20, f_size=    9686, s_size=       44kB, br=   2324.6kbits/s, avg_br=   2256.0kbits/s
----
Peak BR: 12193.2kbits/s
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately neither Mpeg System nor AVC/HEVC specify how to compute instantaneous bitrate. For example, according to Mpeg System spec. the  maximum_bitrate descriptor contains maximal peak bitrate which *"indicates an upper bound of the bitrate, including transport overhead, that will be encountered in this program element or program."*
However, how to compute this bitrate? What window to take (e.g. 1s)? Is it this window sliding (over-lapping) and if so what's hop distance?

Some efforts to standardize bitrate calculations were conducted by DVB. In the document “Measurement guidelines for DVB systems” (old version: ETSI TR 101 290 V1.2.1 (2001-05), the recent version: ETSI TR 101 290 V1.3.1 (2014-07) ) several methods to measure bitrates of transport stream are specified. It's worth mentioning only two - MGB1 and MGB2:

*MGB1
Window (or gate) size is 1s
Sliding:  non-overlapping, the window “hops” each second

MGB2
Window (or gate) size is 1s
Sliding:  overlapping, the window “hops” each 100ms*

In my own site http://ramugedia.com/hls--how-determine-peak-bitrate i gave some explanations how to measure bitrates

Answer (score 1):

I found this old question through Google and ended up building on @Fredrik's helpful response by adding some speed, usability, and correctness improvements.

## Improved answer based on Fredrik Pihl's

```
#!/bin/bash

# Determine the peak bitrate and average bit rate for a video file.
#
# Counts video stream packets directly so can be used when
# video bitrate metadata is incorrect or missing. Very fast.
#
# Usage:
# ./vbit.sh <file> <optional: frames to count> <optional: fps (detected automatically if excluded)> 
#
# Examples:
# ./vbit.sh input.mkv 
# ./vbit.sh input.mkv  10000



frames=$2
# Numper of frames to process
: ${frames:=65536}

fps=$3
# defaults to detecting tbr with ffmpeg
: ${fps:=$(ffmpeg -i $1 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) tbr.*/\1/p")}

echo "FPS=$fps"

awk -v FPS="${fps}" -v FRAMES="${frames}" '
BEGIN{
    FS="="
}
/size/ {
  br=$2/1000.0*8*FPS
  if (br > max_br)
      max_br=br
  acc_br+=br
  acc_bytes+=br
  i+=1

  if (i % 2000 == 0)
    printf("frame= %6d, f_size= %7d, s_size= %8dkB, br= %8.1fkbits/s, avg_br= %8.1fkbits/s\n",
        i, $2, int(acc_bytes/1024+0.5), br, acc_br/i)

  if (i >= FRAMES)
      exit 
}
END {
    print "----"
    printf("Average BR: %.1fkbits/s\n", acc_br/i)
    printf("Peak BR: %.1fkbits/s\n", max_br)
}
' <(ffprobe -select_streams v -show_entries packet=size $1 2>/dev/null)
```

#### Key improvements

- ~100x speed boost by reading packets in order and outputting nothing else but their size.  (key change: `ffprobe -select_streams v -show_entries packet=size`)
- This allows me to count every frame in a 60 minute video in 2s.
- Don't count audio/subtitle streams if they exist (otherwise they're included, making the avg_br incorrect)
- Detect frame rate automatically